# c/c++ BigInteger Implementation for calculating factorial

Tags: c++

How can i implement "Big-Integer" for c/c++ programming? Is there any build function in c/c++ library? or do I have to implement the Function for it?

```
{  
  BigInt fac=1;
  int value=25;
  for(int i=1;i<=25;i++){
    fac=fac*i;
  }
  cout<<fac<<endl;
}
```

I am trying like this but seems like there is no data type like  "Big Int" .

Comment: There's no such thing like a c/c++ language. What made you think, there should be a datatype like `BigInt`? The standards don't provide one. You may lookup finding libraries supporting such though. But asking to recommend one is OT here.

Comment: Programming by guessing (at datatypes and _languages_) is not usually effective :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` if you need an arbitrary precision integer. If you need it to be fast, you can use `boost::multiprecision` with linking to one of several options of an external back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Using a array to store the single integers at a time will help you achieving the desired effect! 
This is the one of the best [tutorial from codechef](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/7349/computing-factorials-of-a-huge-number-in-cc-a-tutorial) for this well known big-int problems!

Hope that helps!